# How can I block all the members of a Facebook group to which I do not belong?

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy

I would like to block the entire member list of a Facebook group, which I do not belong to, all at once. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

The only option provided in the Facebook Help Center page [How do I remove or block someone from a group?](https://www.facebook.com/help/211909018842184) has instructions for removing a **single** member at a time. At this point in time, there is no way to remove **multiple** users from a group easily.

There are some suggestions on the Facebook Help Community such as the question [How to remove multiple members from a group at once?](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=608314279258873) which uses third party tools to *remove* multiple users, but that is not supported by Facebook and does not include blocking users.